# Accordion issue in Chrome Only - Javascript error - 'document.domain'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, frame

I have a collapse/accordion menu I am using and pulling in some facebook bits.

The accordion opens once, but won't open a 2nd time in the Chrome browser (it works great in Firefox)... I get the following error in Chrome.

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FCornish-Roofing-Company%2F226107850785536&width=280&height=290&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=false&header=true from frame with URL http://flux3design.co.uk/crs/. The frame being accessed set 'document.domain' to 'facebook.com', but the frame requesting access did not. Both must set 'document.domain' to the same value to allow access.
```

Any idea what this is... help :(

Cheers

Comment: We don't know either. The error message states quite clearly what happend, if you'd show us the relevant code we could try helping to fix it.

Comment: The website (work in progress) is here http://flux3design.co.uk/crs/ the 2 accordions are on the right hand side, 'Recent Tweets' & Facebook Likes. I just find it strange that it all works great in Firefox, but not Chrome.

Comment: Check the stack trace of the exception. What is the function that accesss the iframe content supposed to do?

Comment: sorry... i'm not a JS person and really don't know how to run a stack trace :(

Comment: Should be a) contained in the error or b) accessible if you set your developer tools to "halt on exception". If you're not the JS person, who did write the code that fails?